# What is the significance of double red circles around node?

Tags: contiki, cooja

[image]I am simulating a simple rpl-udp scenario.  In the radio environment during simulation these double red circles around nodes are showing up ? what exactly does it show ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer was found in the contiki/tools/cooja/java/org/contikios/cooja/plugins/skins/TrafficVisualizerSkin.java file.

/* If there is no destination, paint red circles to indicate untransmitted message */
 mentioned in TrafficVisualizerSkin.java.

```
public void paintBeforeMotes(Graphics g) {
    synchronized (historyList) {
      for (RadioConnectionArrow connArrow : historyList) {
        float colorHistoryIndex = 1.0f - connArrow.getAge();
        Radio source = connArrow.getConnection().getSource();
        Point sourcePoint = visualizer.transformPositionToPixel(source.getPosition());
        /* If there is no destination, paint red circles to indicate untransmitted message */
        if (connArrow.getConnection().getDestinations().length == 0) {
          g.setColor(new Color(UNTRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[0], UNTRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[1], UNTRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[2], colorHistoryIndex));
          g.drawOval(sourcePoint.x - 20, sourcePoint.y - 20, 40, 40);
          g.drawOval(sourcePoint.x - 30, sourcePoint.y - 30, 60, 60);
          continue;
        }
        g.setColor(new Color(TRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[0], TRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[1], TRANSMITTED_COLOR_RGB[2], colorHistoryIndex));
        for (Radio destRadio : connArrow.getConnection().getDestinations()) {
          Position destPos = destRadio.getPosition();
          Point destPoint = visualizer.transformPositionToPixel(destPos);
          drawArrow(g, sourcePoint.x, sourcePoint.y, destPoint.x, destPoint.y, 8);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```